# Lost my ability to connect to Win10 PC in late May 2019

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-xp

I went away for a week, leaving both of my PCs on.  This is a normal occurrence, I leave them running quite frequently.

When I returned, my WinXP PC could no longer connect to my Win10 PC.  It can see the Win10 PC, but it can't connect to any of the drives.

Was there an update done to Win10 in mid-to-late May 2019 that would have tinkered with the ability of a WinXP PC to connect to a Win10 PC?  If so, is there any way to regain the ability to see shared drives?

Windows 10, Version 1803, OS Build 17134.765

Also, the WinXP PC can ping the Win10 PC.

Comment: I haven't used XP in «_mumble_», but I've seen this happen with Windows 7 and Windows 10; the 'fix' was to do `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /flusdns`, and `ipconfig /renew` on both computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Windows 10 is currently running on the PC? And can you check Windows Update History when it updated from a previous version (Feature Update)?

Try to check if SMB1 is enabled. It was disabled by default at some point (but not this year though):

1. Search in the start menu for ‘Turn Windows features on or off’ and
   open it
2. Search for ‘SMB1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support’ in the list of
   optional features that appear, and if not checked then select the checkbox next to it.
3. Click OK and Windows will add the selected feature. You’ll be asked
   to restart your computer as part of this process

Keep in mind that this was disabled for a reason, that it is extremely vulnerable! And you should really update...

Comment: It's Windows 10, Version 1803, OS Build 17134.765.  Interesting that, according to Wiki, 1903 should have rolled out about the same day I lost connectivity, but my PC isn't showing 1903 as the version installed.

Comment: This worked.  Although I'm still curious if it was related to an update or what caused it to just stop connecting.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you triggered this while being away, "If the SMBv1 client is not used for 15 days in total (excluding the computer being turned off), it automatically uninstalls itself." https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-by-default-in-windows